# Linux pdo prepared statement utf-8 issue

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, prepared-statement

This query works normally on windows but on linux it inserts "???". Both use same database engine sql server.

On Linux i use freetds dblib to connect mssql db.

**Php version**

```
7.2
```

**Freetds options**

```
client charset = UTF-8
tds version = 8.0
```

**Query**

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO subjects(name,tenant_id) values(:name, :tenant_id)");
$query->bindValue('tenant_id', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue('name', 'əəƏ', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Thanks dude, i eventually found the problem. But i can't answer my own question. It was dblib problem , I changed it to sqlsrv then the problem was solved.

Comment: Yes, one can Answer one's own Question.  (But perhaps not now that it is a "duplicate".)